# Git Push Hangs on total for bare repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

Pushing a bare repository to BitBucket hangs with no error for hours

```
$ git push -v --mirror https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git

Pushing to https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git
Counting objects: 192778, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (67555/67555), done.
Writing objects: 100% (192778/192778), 59.27 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 192778 (delta 93173), reused 192778 (delta 93173)
POST git-receive-pack (62245326 bytes)
```

At some point, I could see data has been transferred and When I do a ctrl+c and then do a push again, it says, Everything up-to-date. However, it just doesn't complete by itself.

Pushing to a local bare repo just works fine.

```
$ git push --mirror C:/temp/repo.git/

Counting objects: 192778, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (67555/67555), done.
Writing objects: 100% (192778/192778), 59.27 MiB | 21.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 192778 (delta 93173), reused 192778 (delta 93173)
To C:/temp/repo.git/

$ git config --global --list
http.postbuffer=1048576000
sendpack.sideband=false
```

I cannot use ssh as port 22 is blocked in the network. I have pushed 15 more repos using https which worked fine. Only issue with one repository, of 65MB.

Tried pushing through a different network using SSH, works. However, I cannot be doing this always. Looking for a solution to use https.

Comment: How long did you wait before cancelling the push? Depending on the complexity of your project, and especially with the first push, that can take some time.

Comment: I would say few hours, I have went until 3 hours before hitting ctrl+c, however, in 15 mins, I have seen it uploaded the data.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  Why is your `http.postbuffer` set to a gigabyte?

Comment: @Ed - git version 2.9.2.windows.1, I had been trying to increase the postbuffer to see if it does any good. It is now at a GB level. I had 524288000 before this.